# How to test whether there is a statistically significant difference in agreement(Cohen's kappa) between 2 or more independent groups?

Tags: statistical-significance, stata, cohens-kappa

I have 2 methods to compare by difference in race. For example I want to test the agreement between Method 1 and Method 2 between Asians, Americans and Africans.

I know how to calculate kappa seperately for Asians, Americans and Africans. But is there any test in Stata by which we can compare calculated kappa between 3 race groups?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might gain some insight here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509676/testing-the-significant-difference-between-4-kappa-values-in-one-test